# Freezing creates unusual pattern in kern.log

Tags: logging, rootkits, system-compromise

My server freezed a few days ago. After restarting I immediately checked the logs and the only trace I saw were some dots in the kern.log. To my surprise, a day or two later these dots disappeared from the kern.log. Should I suspect that someone rooted the box and covered his tracks or rsyslogd somehow magically cleant this up?

The original:

```
Sep 28 10:30:23 arokr kernel: [49322.004919] audit: type=1305 audit(1411893023.336:1253): auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 op="remove rule" key="audittools" list=4 res=1
........................................Sep 28 10:30:48 arokr kernel: imklog 5.8.11, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
Sep 28 10:30:48 arokr kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
```

Few days later:

```
Sep 28 10:30:23 arokr kernel: [49322.004919] audit: type=1305 audit(1411893023.336:1253): auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 op="remove rule" key="audittools" list=4 res=1
Sep 28 10:30:48 arokr kernel: imklog 5.8.11, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
Sep 28 10:30:48 arokr kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
```

Answer (score 1):

Provided that you accessed the log file on a console, did you have anything running in the background on the same console? If so, it's vaguely possible that whatever you had running in the background printed the dots, and it got intermingled with your view of the log file.

Otherwise, I would take it as a pretty bad sign. Log files generally don't retroactively amend themselves...